# how to upgrade Ubuntu 11.10 to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop DVD

Tags: 11.10, drivers, grub2

I am using dell inspiron 1545 laptop, dual boot OS WinVista & Ubuntu 11.10,
I have got a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin Release i386.iso

I want to Upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 from 11.10 from the dvd. If I insert the dvd into dvd rom drive,computer asking start pakage manager or cancel.

While selecting to start pakage manager, Pakage manager opens and tells "Insert the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin Release i386 dvd in the /media/cdrom" eventhough DVD was inserted in the dvd rom.

Even I tried to eject and insert somany times,Pakage manager didn't find my dvd and asked the same above question.

Please any body to help me to Upgrade the existing Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 LTS.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade from 10.04 or 11.10 to 12.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04)

Answer (score 1):

You need the alternate not the live dvd to upgrade from.

I am not sure there is an alternate dvd.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades#Upgrading_Using_the_Alternate_CD.2BAC8-DVD

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/

There is a 32bit alternate image here http://releases.ubuntu.mirrors.uk2.net/precise/

Comment: I couldn't find the alternate CD image for Ubuntu 12.04 x86 system from the links

Comment: oh - didn't see that, doesn't appear to be a 32bit alternate image

Comment: found one - edited answer

Comment: Thank you Elfy, I am egarly to see the 12.04 desktop and utilities.